# Задание пространственной матрицы весов в стате

Tags: spatial

Всем привет!Очень нужна помощь:у меня есть два эксель файла, в одном файле содержится информация об уровне безработицы в некоторых регионах по годам, во втором файле - матрица грузовых потоков между этими регионами по годам. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в Stata построить пространственную матрицу весов, чтобы потом вычислить индекс Морана. Спасибо